# Knex.js: Make sure people can't buy more products than we have inventory for

Tags: typescript, postgresql, graphql, knex.js

Right now I'm building a webshop for my school guild organization.

I'm not very experienced with databases nor am I any good at using Knex.js

I have an issue when people add things to their carts, if multiple people add things to their carts at the same time sometimes they will have more items in their carts than there is quantity for in the database. I suspect that I have not fully understood transactions and how they work, but if we accidentally sell too many tickets or something similar we are in deep trouble. I would greatly appreciate help with how to do this or pointers to how I can learn to do it better.

This is the code I have tried as of right now to do the transaction:

```js
 private async inventoryToCartTransaction(
    cart: sql.Cart,
    inventoryId: UUID,
    quantity: number = 1,
  ) {
    return this.knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
      const inventory = await trx<sql.ProductInventory>(TABLE.PRODUCT_INVENTORY)
        .where({ id: inventoryId }).first();
      if (!inventory) throw new Error(`Inventory with id ${inventoryId} not found`);
      if (inventory.quantity < quantity) throw new Error('Not enough inventory');
      const product = await trx<sql.Product>(TABLE.PRODUCT)
        .where({ id: inventory.product_id }).first();
      if (!product) throw new Error(`Product with id ${inventory.product_id} not found`);
      const cartItem = await trx<sql.CartItem>(TABLE.CART_ITEM)
        .where({ cart_id: cart.id, product_inventory_id: inventory.id })
        .first();
      const userInventoryItem = await trx<sql.UserInventoryItem>('user_inventory_item').where({
        student_id: cart.student_id,
        product_inventory_id: inventory.id,
      }).first();
      if (cartItem) {
        if ((userInventoryItem ? userInventoryItem.quantity : 0) + cartItem.quantity + quantity > product.max_per_user) throw new Error('You already have the maximum amount of this product.');
        await trx<sql.CartItem>(TABLE.CART_ITEM).where({ id: cartItem.id }).update({
          quantity: cartItem.quantity + quantity,
        });
      } else {
        if ((userInventoryItem ? userInventoryItem.quantity : 0) + quantity > product.max_per_user) throw new Error('You already have the maximum amount of this product.');
        await trx<sql.CartItem>(TABLE.CART_ITEM).insert({
          cart_id: cart.id,
          product_inventory_id: inventory.id,
          quantity,
        });
      }
      await trx<sql.ProductInventory>(TABLE.PRODUCT_INVENTORY).where({ id: inventory.id }).update({
        quantity: inventory.quantity - 1,
      });
      await trx<sql.Cart>(TABLE.CART).where({ id: cart.id }).update({
        total_price: cart.total_price + product.price,
        total_quantity: cart.total_quantity + quantity,
      });
    });
  }
```

This is how the data is structured in the database:

```js
export interface Product {
  id: UUID,
  name: string,
  description: string,
  SKU: string,
  price: number,
  image_url: string,
  max_per_user: number,
  category_id: UUID,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  deleted_at?: Date,
}

export interface ProductCategory {
  id: UUID,
  name: string,
  description: string,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  deleted_at?: Date,
}

export interface ProductInventory {
  id: UUID,
  quantity: number,
  variant: string,
  discount_id?: UUID,
  product_id: UUID,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  deleted_at?: Date,
}

export interface Cart {
  id: UUID,
  student_id: UUID,
  total_price: number,
  total_quantity: number,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  expires_at: Date,
}

export interface CartItem {
  id: UUID,
  cart_id: UUID,
  product_inventory_id: UUID,
  quantity: number,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
}

export interface UserInventory {
  id: UUID,
  student_id: UUID,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  deleted_at?: Date,
}

export interface UserInventoryItem {
  id: UUID,
  student_id: UUID,
  user_inventory_id: UUID,
  product_inventory_id: UUID,
  quantity: number,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  deleted_at?: Date,
}
```

Comment: On `TABLE.CART` at the end, you do `total_price: cart.total_price + product.price,`,  I guess you should do `total_price: cart.total_price + product.price * quantity,`

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be there, you remove `1` from your inventory (`quantity: inventory.quantity - 1,`) but you add `quantity` to the total cart quantity (`total_quantity: cart.total_quantity + quantity,`)

```js
      await trx<sql.ProductInventory>(TABLE.PRODUCT_INVENTORY).where({ id: inventory.id }).update({
        // here
        quantity: inventory.quantity - 1,
      });
      await trx<sql.Cart>(TABLE.CART).where({ id: cart.id }).update({
        total_price: cart.total_price + product.price,
        // and here
        total_quantity: cart.total_quantity + quantity,
      });
```

**Solution**

```js
      await trx<sql.ProductInventory>(TABLE.PRODUCT_INVENTORY).where({ id: inventory.id }).update({
        quantity: inventory.quantity - quantity,
      });
      await trx<sql.Cart>(TABLE.CART).where({ id: cart.id }).update({
        // I'm not sure but I thing you are missing a `* quantity` here
        total_price: cart.total_price + product.price * quantity,
        total_quantity: cart.total_quantity + quantity,
      });
```